# How to Correctly export Material as a texture image?

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I followed multiple tutorials on UV Mapping and exporting a material, but I can't seem to get it right.
I made a texture on a Torus like this:
[image]

And so I tried following multiple tutorials to export it as a PNG image so I can use it in a game, but when I tried applying that PNG texture to the Torus, it looked like this:
[image]

Is there something else I need to do when exporting the UV as a PNG?
And Yes I baked it and the texture looks exactly like the image right above in the game I'm making in Java.

Here's the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: could you please pack the image and share the file? If you still have the original torus, could you please share it as well? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots okay I added the .blend file.

Comment: AFAICT, you're second picture comes from applying the image Baking.001 onto a newly created Torus? The reason it looks different is the newly created Torus.001 does not have the same UVMap as the original Torus. You need to use the image with the same UV map it was baked for.

Comment: it looks like it works fine, give the whole torus a new material, and in this material plug the Image Texture into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF, the UVs are ok. I'm not sure how you got the result you show, maybe share it as well

Comment: As others have said, this is an issue with the UVs. When baking, make sure you have a good UV map because that's how the program is going to decide where to paint the image when baking. Just make sure you don't change the UVs after baking or they won't align with the baked texture.

Smart Project can work for simple shapes, but you can get a better result with some lazy seams. Mark a seam in 3 places: Once along the inner edge loop, then any two edge loops opposite each other on the torus. Then, unwrap. It won't be perfect, but it'll be a lot better than the Smart Project.

Comment: Okay THanks ill try that